# Filter system in ColdFusion 8

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cfquery

I have been working on a small simple project on localhost for a client, it's a comment system with a filter.

But whenever I try to add the filter, it seems to get stuck on it's first word. I've been trying to search the answer on Google for almost 8 hours now, before posting here.

It's a simple query, no complex things. But anyone got any suggestions? I tried the `#` and `cfloop`, `cfoutput`, `cfquery`, etc. but nothing seems to work.

```
<cfquery name = "communityFilter" datasource = "#DSN#">
SELECT *
FROM cms_filter
</cfquery>


<!-- Query van de filter -->
<cfif form.comment CONTAINS communityFilter.word>
    Word gevonden!
<cfelseif NOT form.comment CONTAINS communityFilter.word>
    Geen word gevonden, system werkt =)
</cfif>
```

The system needs to take the word that is not allowed out of the database, but it keeps saying Word found while it's not found.

Comment: To confirm, are you trying to replace bad words within form.comments OR just reject the whole entry? Keep in mind CONTAINS does not look for whole words, so you may get some false positives.

Answer (score 1):

When you refer to a query result, you should specify the row number like this:

```
queryname.fieldname[rownumber]
```

If you don't you get the value from the first row.  That's what is happening to you.  While the comment might contain a bad word, you are not looking at all the available bad words.  I suggest something like this.

```
commentHasBadWord = false;
for (badWord in ValueList(cms_filter.word)) {
if (commentHasBadWord == false && form.comment contains badWord)
commentHasBadWord = true;
else
break;
}

if commentHasBadWord == true;
//code for bad comment
else 
// code for good comment
```